# uibutton skip a distance when move with finger in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I try to move button with finger demo in swift.

So i write a class implement UIButton like bottom.
The problem is that the button will skip a little distance when move.

I want to know why?

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class MoveAbleButton: UIButton {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {}
    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {}
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {}

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.first

        if let touchTemp = touch {
            let t = touchTemp as! UITouch

            let point = t.locationInView(self)

            let x = self.frame.origin.x + point.x
            let y = self.frame.origin.y + point.y
            let w = self.frame.width
            let h = self.frame.height

            self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)

//            let x = self.center.x + point.x
//            let y = self.center.y + point.y
//            
//            let newCenter = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
//            
//            self.center = newCenter

            println("touchesMoved (\(point.x),\(point.y))")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate distant between top-left point of the button and the touch point before moving it.
Here is my code:

```
class MoveAbleButton: UIButton {
var distantX:CGFloat!
var distantY:CGFloat!
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    distantX = ((touches.first as! UITouch).locationInView(self)).x
    distantY = ((touches.first as! UITouch).locationInView(self)).y
}
override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first

    if let touchTemp = touch {
        let t = touchTemp as! UITouch

        let pointInSuperView = t.locationInView(self.superview)

        let x = pointInSuperView.x - distantX
        let y = pointInSuperView.y - distantY
        let w = self.frame.width
        let h = self.frame.height

        self.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)

        //            let x = self.center.x + point.x
        //            let y = self.center.y + point.y
        //
        //            let newCenter = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        //
        //            self.center = newCenter

        //println("touchesMoved (\(point.x),\(point.y))")
    }
}
```

}